# join 2 datatable with and condition caluse LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

hi guy i have 2 datatable like this

```
dt1
id (1,2,3)
name (abc,xyz,def)
num(11,12,13)

dt2
id (1,2,3)
name (abc,xyz,def)
num_from (10,13,11)
num_to   (14,14,14)
```

how could i select id which have num between num_from and num_to using linq
i tried this

```
dtres = (from t1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
        join t2 in dt1.AsEnumerable() on t1.Field<string>("ID") equals t2.Field<string>("ID")
                         where t1["num"]>= t2["num_from"]  &&
                         t1["num"]<= t2["num_to"]
                         select t1).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you tried?

Comment: As I understand you need num in first `DataTable` between `Num_From` and `Num_To` in the second table, please confirm, check the solution underneath

Comment: I don't understand. What should be the result and what do you get from your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Consider the following code:**

It produce the result as `IEnumerable<AnonymousType>`, not `DataRow`, so cannot apply `CopyToDataTable()` extension method, instead I have provided a custom extension method at the bottom of this code `ToDataTable`, you can change the number of columns from the final result, I have included everything.

My understanding from your question is you need a filter such that `Num` in `DataTable1` is between `Num_From` and `Num_To` in the `Datatable2`

```
 var resultDataTable = 
    dt1.AsEnumerable().Join(dt2.AsEnumerable(), t1 => t1["id"], t2 => t2["id"], (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2})
                      .Where(t => (int.Parse(t.t2["num_from"].ToString()) <= int.Parse(t.t1["num"].ToString()) && int.Parse(t.t2["num_to"].ToString()) >= int.Parse(t.t1["num"].ToString())))
                      .Select(t => new { 
                                                     Id1 = t.t1["id"].ToString(), 
                                                     Name1 = t.t1["name"].ToString(), 
                                                     Num1 = t.t1["num"].ToString(), 
                                                     Id2 = t.t2["id"].ToString(), 
                                                     Name2 = t.t2["name"].ToString(), 
                                                     Num_From = t.t2["num_from"].ToString(), 
                                                     Num_To = t.t2["num_to"].ToString()
                                        }
                             ).ToList().ToDataTable();
```

**Extension method to convert IEnumerable to DataTable**

```
public static class ExtensionDT
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this List<T> items)
    {
        var tb = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

        PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            tb.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
        }

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var values = new object[props.Length];
            for (var i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
            {
                values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item, null);
            }

            tb.Rows.Add(values);
        }

        return tb;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome, glad it helped

Comment: a have an other question, your solution it work with 2 dt that i creatae but one of 2 table have datasource from SQL server, it doesnt work anymore,could u show me what happens plz, thank you, Mrinal Kamboj

Comment: Think again about your question, if the Data Table being processed is not there any more, then how would you execute the logic, it is not possible, there's nothing for you to Join. How can you then get the data which is created using both the tables. Check why the DataTable is not getting the data and fix it

Comment: I still using other linq statement to excuted join but using your code is return nothing. My function return datatable from sql server so it still there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a join operation on Linq database is not possible like we do on Mysql and sql. But you can create a simple function to help you do that. You will need a function to return a string or interger for you:

```
   private ObservableCollection<Var_Items> _var_ItemsList;
        public ObservableCollection<Var_Items> Var_ItemsList
        { get { return _var_ItemsList; } 
        set { _var_ItemsList = value;
              NotifyPropertyChanged("Var_ItemsList"); 
        } 
       }

    dtres = from t1 in dt1.AsEnumerable() where t1["num"]>= getMyVar1(t1["num"]) and t1["num"]<= getMyVar1(t1["num"]) select t1;


        public string getMyVar1(int find_var)
        {
            var thisvar = from t2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() where t2["num_from"] >= find_var select t2;
            varitems = new ObservableCollection<Var_Items>(Var_ItemsList);
            return varitems.Last();
        }

        public string getMyVar2(int find_var)
        {
            var thisvar = from t2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() where t2["num_to"] >= find_var select t2;
            varitems = new ObservableCollection<Var_Items>(Var_ItemsList);
            return varitems.Last();
        }
```

I have tried to simplify my answer to be easier to understand. I hope this helps